# Mongoose: update only undefined / unexisting properties and let existing unmodified

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have the following data in mongo:

```
{name: "peter", jobTitle: "engineer", id: 17, webs:[]}
```

and I get more info from him so I want to update the not-existing properties:

new data:

```
{id:17, jobTitle: "gdkjd", phone:"+397373888348", mail:"hello@example.org", webs:["one"],}
```

What I would love to achieve

```
{id:17, name: "peter", jobTitle: "engineer", phone:"+397373888348", mail:"hello@example.org", webs:["one"]}
```

Is there a way to get this without checking individually which properties are already set?

Note: Specially complicated is the idea to add values to the array without overriding it. So less imagine my original array was:

webs: ["two", "three"]

So with this "nonbreaking update" i would expect the database to have this:

webs: ["two", "three", "one"]

Comment: What version of MongoDB?

Comment: mongo 4.2.8
mongoose 5.9.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-array fields, you can get this behavior using the pipeline form of update with the `$mergeObjects` operator.

To handle some fields like arrays specially, assign those first.  Something like:

```
newData={id:17, jobTitle: "gdkjd", phone:"+397373888348", mail:"hello@example.org", webs:["one"]}

db.collection.update({id:newData.id},
                     [
                       {$set:{webs:{$concatArrays:[
                                     {$cond:[
                                         {$eq:[{$type:"$webs"},"array"]},
                                         "$webs",
                                         []
                                     ]},
                                   newData.webs
                       ]}}},
                       {$set:{newDoc:{$mergeObjects:[newData,"$$ROOT"]}}},
                       {$replaceRoot:{newRoot: "$newDoc"}}
                     ]
)
```

Comment: Awesome!
The array thing is not working tho, if the old value have an empty array, no new items are coming :(

Comment: im doing this:
const company = await Company.findOneAndUpdate(
                { id: result.id},
                [
                  {
                    $set: {
                      webs: {
                        $concatArrays: ["$webs", result.webs],
                      },
                    },
                  },

                  { $set: { newDoc: { $mergeObjects: [result, "$$ROOT"] } } },
                  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$newDoc" } },
                ]
              ).exec();

Comment: Hmm, that might be if the previous `webs` was null.  Perhaps using $push with $each would be better?

Comment: $push isn't an aggregation operator, so that won't work.  Perhaps a conditional instead.

Comment: yep tried it and push did not work! But thanks to you i'm getting to understand the logic (i'm new to mongo)

Comment: Tried also [ 
              {$ifNull: ['$array1', []]},
              {$ifNull: ['$array2', []]}
           ] } 
But none is working. I may be doing something wrong, i'm checking everything

Comment: My test with `$cond` (edited into the answer) worked for `webs` being null, nonexistent, undefined, and empty array

Comment: it works! it's the safest option :) Thank you very much!!